# tagged template literals formatted as a string only

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, jsx

I am trying to use tagged template literals along with styled components in VS code, like so:

```
const Component = styled.div`
  margin: 0.5rem 0;


& label {
  font-weight: bold;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
`
```

VS code displays everything inside the tag as a string (so all the code inside is one color). I see lots of tutorials online that render the content inside the tags like normal code (where you have different colors for the various elements) but I cannot figure out how to do that. Can someone help?

Comment: You need the extension for styled components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are looking for - [vscode-styled-components](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=styled-components.vscode-styled-components)